# How to use $Site.Prefix correctly?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html

I have a situation, I want the background of a vfp to be different depending on the url, from what I researched it is possible to do this with $Site.Prefix, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
<apex:page language="{!IF(ISNULL(language),'pt_BR',language)}" id="homePage" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" title="Home" controller="aSiteHomeController" action="{!validate}">
    <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
        <apex:define name="body">
         <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if($Site.Prefix=='portal', true ,false)}"><!--Is here-->
            <body class="nav-md footer_fixed" style="background:#0c4453">   
                <center>
                    <apex:panelGrid bgcolor="#0c4453" columns="1"> 
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <apex:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#0c4453" columns="1" styleClass="topPanelContainer"> 
                            <br/>            
                            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="topPanel">
                                <apex:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#0c4453" columns="1"> 
                                    <apex:panelGroup >
                                        <apex:form id="homeForm">
                                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="jumbotron" style="padding:0px; background:#0c4453" layout="block">
                                                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container" layout="block">
                                                    <h1 style="color:white">Bem-vindo!</h1>
                                                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container" layout="block" rendered="true">
                                                        <p style="margin-bottom: 10px; color:white">Olá, {!User.Name}.<br/>
                                                            Lembre-se do prazo para lançamento dos anexos:<br/><br/>
                                                            Anexo II: Prazo final, 10/07.<br/>
                                                            Anexo III: Prazo Final, 25/11.<br/>
                                                            Anexo IV e V: Prazo Final, 15/03.<br/><br/>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p><a style="background: #0c4453; display: revert; justify-content: center; border-color:#89be48" 
                                                              class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" onclick="goDinamic()">Acessar o Anexo <apex:outputText value="{!anexo}"></apex:outputText>  &raquo;</a></p>
                                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                                    <!--<apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Acesse o Anexo II &raquo;" action="{!gotoAppend2}"/>-->
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                 
                                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container" layout="block" rendered="{!logUser.Habilitado_Anexos__c}">
                                       
                                    </apex:panelGroup>
                                </apex:panelGrid> 
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:panelGrid> 
                    </apex:panelGrid>
                </center>
            </body>
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:define>
    </apex:composition>
 

   
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Site.Prefix` returns the URL with the preceding `/` on it, so in your case it returns `/portal`.

Your conditional uses just `portal`, whereas it should be `/portal`:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Site.Prefix == '/portal'}"> ...
```

And in this case you don't need to wrap it in an "if" statement because the evaluation of the `==` expression will return a boolean anyway.

Comment: thanks for your time and help!